# Add input features for transfer learning? (Not for CNN)

Tags: machine-learning, transfer-learning

I've trained a robot to walk forward using the TD3 algorithm, where the input features are the robot's joint states, roll pitch & yaw, accelerations, and position. Now I want to use this trained model to get it to stop on a target, which involves adding the input features x and y as coordinates for where to stop.

How should I approach adding features to the model without having to train it from scratch? (Nearly every resource I found was targeted for CNNs, which have a pooling layer which makes it easy to use the same model for different image sizes, so that won't apply here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the lack of information on it, it's actually quite simple.
In PyTorch, just load the state_dict and use `new_state_dict = torch.cat((weights_tensor, new_column_tensor), dim=-1)` to tack on a new randomized column to the weight tensor in the pkl file (not for biases). Then just use `torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)`!